# Best practice for adding logging in azure app service and make sure not to lose any log?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am switching my application to Azure. I have added application insight for application logging. Few more other loggings also I have added like: Web Server Logging, Detailed Error Messages and Failed Request Tracing. I want to make sure every detail is logged well. Do we have any other loggings? and What are the best practices?

Comment: [Enable diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to remember when using applications that makes it easy to not log everything is that sampling is enabled by default in some instances, so if you want to make sure to log absolutely everything then sampling needs to be turned off, now I am not saying this is a good idea but that is a different topic.

As for the logging itself there are plenty of good tutorials on the Internet to read, and if you really want all you might need to enable diagnostic logging as well but prepare for a lot of noice.

I think it is better to really think about what logs you really ened and make sure those get injected into app insights and go from there

Comment: Actually, I am working for a client who doesn't know much about Azure. So I kinda need everything that can help them out to easily figure out if anything goes wrong.

Comment: @Psychonaut007 sure but its easy to miss things when you get over whelmed with logs, and if you have multiple apps etc then I suggest you feed all your app insihgts into a log analytics workspace for centralised queries etc across applications